# React js. Как выложить файл пользователю для скачивания

Tags: javascript, файлы, reactjs, download

В компоненте есть набор кнопок, по клику на которые пользователь должен получить диалог сохранения файла для соответствующих файлов. Файлы типа exe и pdf. 
Попыталась вот так:

```html
   var pathToFile = "../../public/resource/"; 
   downloadFile(file) {
        var tempLink = document.createElement('a');
        tempLink.href = pathToFile;
        tempLink.setAttribute('download', file);
        tempLink.click();
    }
```

Вызываю эту функцию по клику на кнопки с соответствующим файлом в качестве параметра. Функция вызывается, но temkLink.click() не срабатывает.Что я неправильно делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось совсем просто:

```html
var pathToFile = "....";
downloadFile(file) {
    location.href = pathToFile + file;
}
```

И сразу вызывается диалог скачать или открыть.

Answer (score 0):

А где типы и создания ссылки на файл, чтобы передавать?
Все работает нормально:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unmf5dp0/)

```js
/* Inside your Ajax success callback */

// Just for the demo
var res = "0;test0\n1;test1\n2;test2";

var data = new Blob([res], {
    type: 'text/csv'
  }),
  csvURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(data),
  tempLink = document.createElement('a');
tempLink.href = csvURL;
tempLink.setAttribute('download', 'myCSVFile.csv');
tempLink.click();
```

Comment: Посмотрела ссылку, не очень поняла. Не могли бы Вы поподробнее ответить? Что такое  переменная "res" и надо ли мне ее просто скопировать или как-то изменить?

Comment: Попробовала в качестве res вставить свой путь, не работает. И ошибки не возникает. То есть похоже, что клик просто не срабатывает.

Comment: Напишите alert(1); в теле объекта (функции) downloadFile - в самом начале и посмотрите будет ли он срабатывать, если нет, то косяк где - то в другом месте и вы даете не тот скрипт-код.